# Creating user login using session_start() in PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

When a user logs in on my website using his username/password combination, the following code runs:

```
 if($user == $_POST['username'] && $password == $_POST['password']){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   }
```

Then on another page that I limit access only to the logged in users, I have before any other  code this piece of php:

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo '<script>alert("You do not have access to this page. Please log in first.");</script>';
    header("Location: createAccount.php");
    exit();}
?>
```

That basically should send the user to the createAccount.php page if they don't have one. The code seems quite straightforward but doesn't work for some reason. Is it my understanding of sessions that's flawed?

Comment: Is the leading space in the second block of code in your file?

Comment: this code should work . Please tell  me how you are testing this code . Browser should be same and not closed after logged in .By default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.

Comment: @user2182349 No it's not (Stackoverflow formatting)

Comment: too many unknowns; use error reporting and var_dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a header after starting any other output.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: createAccount.php");
    exit();}
?>
```

Should work for you - IF this is at the very start of the file..  If you want, you can set a session error message variable and on createAccount.php check to see if it exists and print a pretty "you gotta log in or create an account" message.